# Error - Can not find the tag library descriptor for "/struts-tags"

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I'm receiving this error on my jsp file - 'Can not find the tag library descriptor for "/struts-tags"'

Strange thing is my app still seems to work.

I'm following the tutorials at - http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/using-struts-2-tags.html

Here is the code.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%> 
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html> 
  <head> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"> 
      <title>Hello World!</title> 
  </head> 
  <body>  
      <h2><s:property value="messageStore.message" /></h2>  
      <p>I've said hello <s:property value="helloCount" /> times!</p>  
      <p><s:property value="messageStore" /></p> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: Show the relevant code of your JSP.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Have you added the struts2-core-.jar to the libraries of the project? If you have try to clean the project.

Comment: Same problem, the struts 2 jar were added by maven into the WEB-INF/lib folder but I still had this error in all my jsps. A project "clean" solved it.

Answer (score 7):

In ECLIPSE:
Right click on the project and select the option "Validate". That's all.

Comment: What does validata option do in Eclipse? @htobon

Comment: I thought this was too easy, but I can confirm that the error message disappeared by doing this. Magic.

Comment: @Pie : the validate menu entry starts the validation process; checks all files according to their syntax (.java files against java syntax, .jsp against JSP syntax, .html, .js, .css, .xml and so on).

Answer (score 1):

This is probably Eclipse getting a bit 'confused' rather than a genuine error.

I had the same thing yesterday when working through a Struts 2 tutorial, but it disappeared after opening/closing the JSPs.

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened to me. I am using Maven to compile. So, I disabled and re-enabled Maven in my project and that solved it.

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar problem. This is what I did to resolve the issue.

1.Select Project and right click.
2.Click on properties.
3.Click on libraries tab.
4.Click on 'Add Jars'.
5.Add relavent jar for your error.

hope this helps. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem because I copied the libraries manually and directly into the folder `WEB-INF/lib` of the project and eclipse doesn't see them (I suggest you copy any necessary libraries into `WEB-INF/lib` only through eclipse!). So only a refresh of the project solved the problem for me because all the other solutions didn't work!!

(I'm using Eclipse Kepler unber Ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

As William mentioned, this sounds like your IDE may not know where the TLD for the tag library is in your project, but once packaged and running, it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

add struts2-core-.jar to the project

download it here

http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/index.html

Answer (score 0):

go to Project tab > Clean..
Even if cleaning the project doesn't clear the error, right-click on the project and click refresh

Then right-click on the project, go to properties, Java Build Path >> 'Order and Export' tab >> make sure JRE library and Maven dependencies are checked.

that would probably solve it as it did for me