# eclipse : Can not find the tag library descriptor for "/struts-tags"

Tags: java, eclipse, struts2, struts, taglib

I am following the steps given in

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/struts_quick_guide.htm

for a sample struts 2 application

but I am getting following error message : 
`Can not find the tag library descriptor for "/struts-tags`

I followed several helps :

1. [Error - Can not find the tag library descriptor for "/struts-tags"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050712/error-can-not-find-the-tag-library-descriptor-for-struts-tags)
2. [Cannot find the tag library descriptor for /WEB-INF/struts-html.tld in Struts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14374311/can-not-find-the-tag-library-descriptor-for-web-inf-struts-html-tld-in-struts)

still the error persists.. what shall I do?
Thanks

Comment: After you added the struts jars to the WEB-INF\lib folder of the project, did you clean and rebuild?

Comment: Do you have a WAR only, or an EAR ? And if the latter, is the struts-core.x.x.x.jar in the EAR ? If yes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19380932/1654265

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error - Can not find the tag library descriptor for "/struts-tags"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050712/error-can-not-find-the-tag-library-descriptor-for-struts-tags)

Answer (score 2):

This message can be produced if the `struts2-core-[VERSION].jar` is not marked as an Export Dependency.

To correct this:

`Project Properties > Java Build Path > Order and Export`

Then mark `struts2-core-[VERSION].jar` as an Export Dependency (or, if included via Ivy, make sure the Ivy library is marked as an Export Dependency).

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the struts2-core-.jar to the libraries of the project? Clean the project. The error will go away.